# Add current_user to nested model in Create and Update - Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, parameters

I have 2 models `Collection` and `Post` and posts are nested in collections:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts,  allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['title'].blank?  }
```

I want to add current user's id to posts in controller so I defined a private method to add user_id to each post in collection_params like this:

```
def add_user_and_in_collection_to_posts(collections_params)

  posts_params=collection_params[:posts_attributes]
  posts_params.each { |key,post|
    unless post[:title].blank? 
      post[:user_id]=current_user.id 
    end        
  }
    collection_params[:posts_attributes]=posts_params
    p "^^^^^^^XXX^^^^^^^^^"
    p posts_params
    p collection_params
    p "vvvvvvvXXXvvvvvvvvvv"


end
```

In logs user_id will be added to posts_params but even with assigning `posts_params` to `collection_params[:posts_attributes]`, `collection_params` won't change.

My questions are:

First, **Is it the best way to add user ID to Posts?**

Second, **Why collection_params won't change?**

Comment: Where do you define `collection_params` ?

Comment: @nicohvi I think `collection_params` is defined by rails and is used in update and create methods in controllers. I used scaffolding to generate my controllers etc...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. collections_param is a method generated by rails and permits the whitelisted attributes so you can add attributes to collection_params before returning the hashmap like this:

```
def collection_params
  permited_params=params.require(:collection).permit(:title,:published,:destination_url,posts_attributes: [:id,:title,:_destroy,])
  posts_params=permited_params[:posts_attributes]
  posts_params.each { |key,post|
    unless post[:title].blank? 
      post[:user_id]=current_user.id 
    end
  }
  permited_params
end
```